# Formatting decimal numbers with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Codename One does not allow me to use DecimalFormat. So how do I work around this code:

```
private final static DecimalFormat balanceFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

private final String GetWalletBalanceEndpoint = "wallet/balance";
public GetWalletBalance() {
    super();
    endpoint = GetWalletBalanceEndpoint;
}

public final Double getBalance() {
    Map<String, Object> balanceMap = getResponseData();
    Double balance = (Double) balanceMap.get("balance");
    return balance;
}


public String getBalance2DecimalsString() {
    Double balance = getBalance();
    return balanceFormatter.format(balance);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format decimals in Codename One using the L10NManager

```
private final L10NManager lnm = L10NManager.getInstance();

private final String GetWalletBalanceEndpoint = "wallet/balance";
public GetWalletBalance() {
    super();
    endpoint = GetWalletBalanceEndpoint;
}

public final String getBalance() {
    Map<String, Object> balanceMap = getResponseData();
    return lnm.format(Double.parseDouble(balanceMap.get("balance").toString), 2);
}
```

**Note** that values will be formatted based on the device localization. Some countries write `10.34` as `10,34`, this format will be followed. You can force a particular country's format by setting the localization before formatting:

```
lnm.setLocale("US", "EN");
```